# Error while attempting to install pywin32 package in pycharm in raspberry pi 4b

Tags: python, installation, package, pywin32, raspberry-pi4

I got this error message while trying to install the `pywin32` package in pycharm 3.7 in my raspberry-pi4b...Is there any problem in pycharm version for pywin32 package?
Please help me to solve this problem as soon as possible. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with PyCharm. You are trying to install Python Extensions for *Windows* on a Raspberry Pi which is not a Windows machine.

Comment: Kindly don't add images in l external inks , you can upload images in stackoverflow itself.

Comment: Ohk..Thank you (-BoarGules) 

Comment: Ohk..sure (-Sameera DeSilva)